# Emitting ES5 with Webpack 2

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript2.0, webpack-2

I've been playing around with Webpack 2, and switching my TypeScript to ES6 mode to take advantage of tree-shaking. That's all cool, but the problem is now I am using ES6 in production, while not all browsers support that yet.

How can I tell Webpack to emit ES5 **after tree-shaking is done**?

Comment: Why do you want to emit ES5 after tree shaking is done? I think typescript now supports es6 modules with es5 target https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6319

Comment: @TamasHegedus because I use `babili` to minify the es6 code due to UglifyJS not supporting it, and I need to target ES6 to avoid `(<any>Object).assign()`

Comment: Well, I guess you could compile the resulting es6 bundle with babel afterwards. I didnt find a way to make webpack do it yet.

Comment: @TamasHegedus do you think it's necessary? I'm only targeting _actual_ browsers (meaning no IE)

Comment: I would configure babel plugins/presets to my needs. So you wish to compile *some* es6 features to es5, but not all?

Comment: I want the end-result to run in all major browsers. :)

Comment: And why do you think telling webpack to emit es5 would not do the same? (i mean compiling it with babel es2015 preset)

Comment: Because I am using TypeScript and not Babel - I use `babili-webpack-plugin` to minify ES6 code because Uglify does not understand it. This is because I am telling TypeScript to target ES6 so I can use ES6 features in my code.

Comment: Just a sidenote: What about using rollupjs with typescript plugin?

Comment: Instead of webpack?

Comment: yes, instead of webpack. Rollupjs was the first to introduce treeshaking, it is built into it, it does not rely on babili. I think its worth to take a look.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, webpack has nothing to do with typescript in your configuration as you feed es6 into it outputted by the typescript compiler right? I think in this case the only way to go is to introduce a separate compilation step at the end from es6 to es5+non-trash-browser-features. And the most reliable compiler for that is still babel.

Comment: Babili is just an ES6 minifier, it does not do tree-shaking. Webpack does the tree-shaking on ES6 code emitted by TypeScript (`ts-loader`) and that ES6 is piped to `babili` which minifies it. At that point we have ES6, which Webpack then performs tree-shaking on. When that's done, we still have ES6, and webpack is done. I guess I then have to invoke babel on the webpackified code? Is that the only way?

Comment: Based on this article, webpack2 uses babilis dead code elimination to simulate tree-shaking http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html

Comment: Oh, apologies - didn't know.

Comment: Neither did I to this day

Comment: So I guess I'll need an additional compilation step - this is just because TypeScript does not want to play nice. :(

Comment: By the way, avoiding `(<any>Object).assign` is a common problem https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3005

Comment: So what about using typescript with `target:"es5", modules:"es6", lib:["es6"]`, and then feeding it to webpack2+babili?

Comment: Yes that actually does help a bit - not just having trouble with the code being emitted, hehe :P